# Call Java from Javascript and pass integer

Tags: java, javascript

I use java to evaluate a javascript file. This is using java.lang.String.format and shall pass an integer, but I get the exception for "java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double". My passed value seems to be converted to double.

javascript:

```
java.lang.String.format("%02d", 1 );
```

How can I enforce that the passed variable type is int?

Comment: try this: int myInt = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf("1"));

Comment: I want to use the String.format function to do more formating. I figured out "java.lang.String.format("%02d", new java.lang.Integer(1) );" works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an `Integer` explicitly:

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript")
    .eval("java.lang.System.out.format('%d', new java.lang.Integer(1));");
```

The JavaScript `Number` type is equivalent to the Java `Double` type. Because the format takes `Object` types the method signature doesn't have enough metadata to tell the script engine to coerce the type to an `Integer`.